# undefined global 'vim' in lua-language-server - coc.nvim

Tags: vim-plugins, lua, neovim

This snippet gives a warning:
`local api = vim.api  #Undefined global 'vim'`

my CocConfig:

```
`  "languageserver": {
    "lua": {
      "command": "/home/manas/.config/coc/extensions/coc-sumneko-lua-data/sumneko-lua-ls/extension/server/bin/Linux/lua-language-server",
      "args": [
        "-E",
        "/home/manas/.config/coc/extensions/coc-sumneko-lua-data/sumneko-lua-ls/extension/server/main.lua"
      ],
      "filetypes": [
        "lua"
      ],
      "rootPatterns": [
        ".git/"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "Lua": {
          "workspace": {
            "library": {
              "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua": true,
              "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim": true,
              "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp": true
            },
            "maxPreload": 2000,
            "preloadFileSize": 1000
          },
          "runtime": {
            "version": "5.4.1"
          },
          "diagnostics": {
            "disable": [
              "undefined-global",
              "lowercase-global",
              "unused-local",
              "unused-vararg",
              "trailing-space"
            ],
            "globals": [
              "vim",
              "hs",
              "it",
              "describe",
              "before_each",
              "after_each"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow the process from URL: https://github.com/sumneko/lua-language-server/wiki/Build-and-Run, to install `lua-language-server` manually.
2. Startup neovim, enter command: `:CocConfig`。
3. Edit the file: `coc-settings.json`

```json
{
  "languageserver": {
    "lua": {
      "command": "/home/alanjui/.local/share/lua-language-server/bin/Linux/lua-language-server",
      "args": [
        "-E",
        "/home/alanjui/.local/share/lua-language-server/bin/Linux/main.lua"
      ],
      "filetypes": ["lua"],
      "settings": {
        "Lua": {
          "workspace.library": {
            "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua": true,
            "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim": true,
            "/usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp": true
          },
          "diagnostics": {
            "globals": [ "vim" ]
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [`coc-sumneko-lua`](https://github.com/xiyaowong/coc-sumneko-lua).
2. Add the following line to your [`coc-setting.json`](https://github.com/Martins3/My-Linux-Config/blob/master/coc-settings.json).

   ```
   "sumneko-lua.enableNvimLuaDev": true,
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

All `coc-lua` needs is a `"Lua.diagnostics.globals": ["vim"]` in your `coc-settings.json`.

Comment: that would disable the autocompletion and good stuff 
https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#lua_ls check this please

Answer (score 1):

actually lua lsp itself has clearly explains what to do in the [docs here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#lua_ls).

1. You install coc-lua by running `:CocInstall coc-lua`
2. open coc-settings by running `:CocConfig`
3. as stated in the linked docs above just add the following
   -> "Lua.runtime.version":"LuaJIT"
   ->

```
    "Lua.workspace.library":[
        "<value of $VIMRUNTIME variable>"
     (you can just do <c-r>=$VIMRUNTIME to insert it there)
    ]
```

4. after all just do a `:CocRestart` and you are good to go